# How could I have the error message go automatically when the input field is no longer required?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am working with an [antd input field](https://ant.design/components/form/) and trying to toggle between the `required = true` state and `required=false` state and I noticed a peculiar case where the error message does not go away when input field is no longer required. I am not sure why does not `antd` handle this situation itself.

Here is what I do:

- Input field is initialised as `required`
- I write something and then erase, which gives the message "Please input your username" as shown in the image
- Then I click, `Click to toggle input field` button. This changes the input field state from `required = true` to `required = false`.
- But the error message remains. How could I have the error message go automatically when the input field is no longer required?

[image]

Here is the small demo of the above image I created at codesandbox:

[image: Edit determined-williams-cctpp]

Here is also the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';


class HorizontalLoginForm extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      enable: true
    };

    this.onButtonClick = this.onButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  onButtonClick() {
    this.setState({
      enable: !this.state.enable
    })
  }

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    const {enable} = this.state;

    return (
      <Form layout="inline">
        <Form.Item>
          {getFieldDecorator('username', {
            rules: [{ required: this.state.enable, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
          })(
            <Input disabled = {!enable}
            />,
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item>
          <Button type="primary" onClick={this.onButtonClick}>
            Click to toggle input field
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedHorizontalLoginForm = Form.create({ name: 'horizontal_login' })(HorizontalLoginForm);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedHorizontalLoginForm />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: The sandbox code is a login form with username and password fields. There is no "Click to toggle input field button"

Comment: @AvinKavish Sorry, but I did not understand your comment.

Comment: @AvinKavish Sorry, updated. Had pasted the incorrect link earlier.

Comment: You've added content when the user removes their data, so now you need to check if this data is present when the toggle is clicked, if it is, remove it. Or you could add something to the error code so that it's only visible if disable is false?

Comment: @AriVictor Did not understand. Could you help with an example?

Comment: Antd seems to be running validation on the blur event of the input control. Merely toggling required does not trigger re-validation. I think it's a short coming on their part. (which is why I moved away from antd libraries) Look for a function to manually force re-validation and call it on your button click handler.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no way to achieve this kind of behaviour as the Form.Item sets new validation state only on onInput call (when you enter something into Input inside) and therefore it doesn't take the 'required' switch into account.

In case if you need to change the validation behaviour you can go around with a simple solution like:

```
{enable ? 
      (<Form.Item>
      {getFieldDecorator('username', {
        rules: [{ required: this.state.enable, message: 'Please input your username!' }],
      })(
        <Input disabled = {!enable}
        />,
      )}
    </Form.Item>) :
   <Form.Item>
     <Input disabled = {!enable} />
   </Form.Item>`}
```

The only caveat of this solution is that it will hide the previously entered value on change of the 'enable' switch but you can save them anywhere in your state and then assign the default input value to the value of this 'state entered value'